# Derivation of parametric integral function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Good afternoon,

consider the integral function $f(x):=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\cos(xt)}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$. I would like to derive $f$ with respect to $x$ to obtain $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{t\sin(xt)}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$, but the integral is not absolutely convergent and Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem cannot be applied here to justify the derivation under the integral sign. How could one proceed here?

Comment: If the integral is correct as you've written it, you can just evaluate the integral with respect to $t$, but the derivative of the integrand with respect to x is incorrect, so is the denominator of the integrand $\sqrt{t^2+1}$, rather than $\sqrt{x^2+1}$?

Comment: @mcd thank you for pointing it out. I wrote the denominator incorrectly, now I corrected my question

Comment: For a "closed form", see [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11) (at $\nu=0$).

Comment: @metamorphy thank you. Yes I know that my function $f$ represents the Bessel function $K_0$, but I was rather looking for a theoretical argument to prove (or possibly disprove) the derivation under the integral sign, since the obvious theorems that are usually employed (Lebesgue' theorem, Leibniz' criterion) fail in the present case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t \sin(xt)}{\sqrt{t^{2}+1}} \, \mathrm dt$ doesn't converge.

However,  we can put $f(x)$ in a form that allows us to differentiate under the integral sign.

Assume that $x>0$.

Notice that $$\begin{align} f(x) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(xt) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}- \frac{\boldsymbol{1}_{t > 1}}{t} \right) \, \mathrm dt + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos xt}{t} \, \mathrm dt \\ &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(xt) \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}- \frac{\boldsymbol{1}_{t > 1}}{t} \right) \, \mathrm dt - \operatorname{Ci}(x), \end{align}$$ where $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$ is the [cosine integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

Differentiating both sides, we get $$\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x) &= -\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(xt) \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}- \boldsymbol{1}_{t > 1}  \right) \, \mathrm dt - \frac{\cos(x)}{x} \\ &=  -\int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(xt) \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}-1  \right) \, \mathrm dt - \frac{1}{x} \end{align}$$

since $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(xt) \, \mathrm dt = \frac{1- \cos(x)}{x}$.

Differentiating under the integral sign was permissible since $\left| -\sin(xt) \left( \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}- \boldsymbol{1}_{t > 1}\right) \right|$ is dominated on $[0,1]$ by $1$ and dominated on $(1, \infty)$ by $\left(1- \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}} \right)$.

And since $f(x)$ is an integral representation of $K_{0}(x)$, we have

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}K_{0}(x) = - K_{1}(x) = -  \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(xt) \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}-1 \right) \, \mathrm dt - \frac{1}{x}. $$

Comment: very nice proof, thank you very much! I still have a problem where you use dominated convergence on the $(1,\infty)$ interval with the function $1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$: how to see that this integral is convergent?

Comment: @atomion, $$0<1-\dfrac t{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+t^2}\left(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}\right)}<\dfrac1{t^2}\;\;,$$ hence the integral is convergent on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @atomion   We can also find the value of the integral. $$\begin{align} \int_{1}^{\infty} \left(1- \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}} \right)  \, \mathrm dt &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left( t - \sqrt{1+t^{2}} \bigg|_{1}^{b} \right)\\ &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(b- \sqrt{1+b^{2}} \right) -(1-\sqrt{2}) \\ &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(b- b \sqrt{1+ \frac{1}{b^{2}}}  \right)-(1-\sqrt{2}) \\ &=  \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(b- b \left(1+ O \left(\frac{1}{b^{2}} \right) \right)  \right)-(1-\sqrt{2}) \\ &= \sqrt{2}-1 \end{align}$$

Comment: @Angelo and RandomVariable: now I understand the proof, thank you!